# Moving a many to many to a one to one in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, one-to-one, rails-migrations, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have a relationship between two models that is currently a many to many. I'd like to move it to a one to one relationship, because that's what all of the data has turned out to be.

Is there a seamless way to do this? Via a migration and model change combo?  My models would be simple to just change as shown below:

Now

```
class App < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :owners
end

class Owner < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :apps
end
```

Changing to

```
class App < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :owner
end

class Owner < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :app
end
```

But how do I update the database to reflect these changes without losing any of the data I currently have?

Comment: You're gonna duplicate a lot of data in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an `owner_id` field to your `apps` table and then iterate through your `apps_owners` table and set the `owner_id` field in `apps` to the `owner_id` field in `apps_owners` for the `apps` record whose `id` is equal to `app_id`.

Assuming you're correct and there aren't multiple `apps_owners` entries for the same `app_id` following SQL should do it (not tested), although I'm not familiar with how to incorporate raw SQL into migrations:

```
update apps set owner_id=(select owner_id from apps_owners where apps.id = apps_owners.app_id)
```

Comment: Couldn't you "migrate" back by doing a similar sql query?  This one would be in the `up` with an `add_column` call and the other would be in the `down`

Comment: I'm sure you're right. I've never thought of extending migrations to include raw SQL, but I'm sure it's possible.

Comment: I think it actual turned out to be pretty simple, but I haven't tested it yet (yours works though!), but to migrate backwards from this you'd do `execute "INSERT INTO apps_owners (app_id, owner_id) SELECT id, owner_id FROM apps"`

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to do this simply.  The main problem is that `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationships use a tertiary database table (`apps_owners` in your case) to hold the relationship information.

After you create the appropriate migration to add `owner_id` to your `App` model, you'll need to create a rake task that reads the `app_owner` table and re-creates the relationships.

Comment: I could assume most of that, but the complicated part is obviously the rake task